# Using Tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use Tikz package to draw markov chains.

I gave these commands to use tikz package,

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

But i am getting an error as follows.

> LaTeX Error: File `xcolor.sty' not found.Type X to quit or  to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.

Can someone point out the error. I just started using latex.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. The error indicate, that you haven't installed `xcolor` package. Which LaTeX distribution and editor you use?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the dependent packages such as `xcolor`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem is most likely caused by installing the missing package, but without more information about the system, specific advice is not possible to give.